# How to pass Hasura action handler url from environment variables?

Tags: hasura

I am creating some Hasura actions to handle custom logic.  My backend is running on http://localhost:3002. I want the handler's URL's first portion to get from an environment variable.

[image]

I also added  `ACTION_RESOLVER_API_ENDPOINT: "http://localhost:3000"` to the environment section of the **docker-compose.yml** file

I want the URL to be like this.

`${ACTION_RESOLVER_API_ENDPOINT}/<functionName>`  how to access that variable and use it in the handler section of the Hasura console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the input the following value:

`{{ACTION_BASE_ENDPOINT}}/functionName`

and the ACTION_BASE_ENDPOINT will come from the ENV variable with the same name.

Comment: It should also be between quotes: `"{{ACTION_BASE_ENDPOINT}}/functionName"`